# What is the difference between Prophoto's Zoom Reflector and Wide Zoom reflector?

Tags: lighting, off-camera-flash, lighting-modifiers, reflectors, profoto

On [Profoto Zoom Reflector page](http://profoto.com/int/products/light-shaping-tools-modular-light-shapers-for-profoto-heads-monolights/hard-reflectors/item/zoom-reflector),
it says Light spread: **105° at position 10**, and in [Wide Zoom Reflector page](http://profoto.com/int/products/light-shaping-tools-modular-light-shapers-for-profoto-heads-monolights/hard-reflectors/item/widezoom-reflector)
It says **80° at position 10**.

So isn't 105 degrees wider than 80 degrees? Then why the other one is called "Wide" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into technicalities, I can provide some user experience.

Having hired both reflectors for a previous job; firstly, the Zoom reflectors were a lot smaller, 7-8in in diameter and about 6in depth and the Widezoom reflector was a lot larger, about twice the size from what I can recall.
The zoom reflector at position 10 gave a harder shadow than the Widezoom at position 10, maybe it was the actual size of the reflector doing this.

Due to the larger size of the wide zoom, the lightspread was very definitely softer. 
I was photographing the front quarter of a car, i.E front light, wheel arch with half of the front grill and needed hard light fall off, so opted for the Zoom Reflector and used the wide zoom as a fill in side light.

The figures you mention, could be something to do with the actual size of the reflectors, but it also may have something to do with the zoom reflector sitting further back at position 10.
Either way, the wide zoom definitely had a softer spread of light and I would have preferred it for fashion.